# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Overflow (Long valid range -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

While executing an Redshift insert query,one of the values occurring is **45145124512145554112124** which is exceeding the range of long `(Long valid range -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)`. In such a case, what can be done to include this record so that even other records which are within the range also gets inserted successfully? How to handle Redshift overflow error?

Comment: Simply sanitise the data before ever `insert`ing it..?

Comment: @underscore_d : Do you know any way of sanitizing the data in Redshift??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NUMERIC` data type can hold values up to 128 bits in length. Specify the data type in the case as `NUMERIC(38,0)`.

Please note that you should not do this unless you *need* the extra length `NUMERIC` allows.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html